# Is there any reason for the [stackoverflow-teams] tag existing on the main site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just noticed a question about Stack Overflow for Teams that was migrated from the main site. I was curious about what tags were used and checked. One was [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) (used incorrectly, of course) but there was one other that caught my eye.

[stackoverflow-teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-teams) is a tag on the main site that has no tag brief/wiki and only 2 questions, both of which are about Stack Overflow for Teams and don't seem to have anything to do with programming (and both were migrated here too, I believe). Is there any reason for this tag existing on the main site? I've never used Stack Overflow for Teams, so maybe there's some programming involved that warrants a tag existing on the main site? I highly doubt that though. I also don't think there is anything else called Stack Overflow Teams that has anything to do with programming, but I might just be missing something.

Comment: The tag was probably created by mistake by one of the people who asked the question on the main site, as the _two_ questions created on it have been migrated. Shouldn't take long for it to be deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag was created by [user MetaMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/metaman) by accident.

They asked a question on the main site about Stack Overflow for Teams, which got migrated to meta. This question had the [stackoverflow-teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-teams), which was created because of the [Create Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege.

A mod can delete it really easily.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The [stackoverflow-teams] tag was added by another user *after* the migration to Meta.

Comment: @cigien is there a way to see when a tag was created?

Comment: @cigien but how/why would the original question be seemingly retagged to include [stackoverflow-teams] afterwards then? (10rep so sorry for unaccepting! I thought things had cleared up fully)

Comment: Oh, never mind. I misread that. The [stack-overflow-for-teams] tag was added by another user. It seems the [stackoverflow-teams] tag was added on the main site. And no, I don't know how to check when a tag was created, but I'm sure there's some way to do that.

Comment: Ah, it seems it's been cleared up then (at least I think, I don't know how to check when it was created either :/). I'll reaccept the answer then, thanks.

Comment: @cigien I think it's impossible to find it for small tags without doing a wiki edit. [This is the info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow-teams/info), which gives almost no information :|

Comment: @10Rep When I try to edit the tag wiki, I don't see anything either, so maybe it's not visible for some reason.

Comment: *Provided* no one creates any more posts with this tag, it *should* eventually get cleaned up anyway by the roomba when the migrated questions are deleted on [main], and then the tag shortly afterwards.

Comment: @10Rep of course [there's sede.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1403583?tagname=stackoverflow-teams)

Comment: @Larnu that theory has a problem, the migration stub will be there for 30 days, which would tell the system that the tag exists.

Comment: @Braiam that's useful, thanks! So my theory is now confirmed :)

Comment: I did was *eventually*, @Braiam ; it'll take awhile but once both are deleted the tag should go with them a little afterwards.

Comment: Are burninated tags put within a blacklist, better if with also the main possible synonims (in case of `stackoverflow-teams`, for example, also [`stack-overflow-teams`, `so-teams` etc...)?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni IIRC blacklisting a tag is a really legnthy process that only a dev can do. It's very intensive and only done if a tag is making an extreme comeback after a burnination.